# How often was the 'abominable mystery' used to attack Darwin's evolution theory?

Tags: science, victorian

Darwin coined the words "[abominable mystery](https://ecoevocommunity.nature.com/posts/16792-darwin-s-abominable-mystery)" for the comparatively sudden appearance of flowering plants in the fossil record, and [considered it a weak point in his evolution theory](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21628174/).

But from what I have learned, not many people used/use that to argue against Darwin's theory. I only find one from [New light shed on Charles Darwin's 'abominable mystery'](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-55769269):

> A lecture from 1876 by the Scottish botanist William Carruthers...
> Carruthers was using the abominable mystery to launch an attack on
> evolution itself," says Prof Buggs. "He thought that God had created
> the angiosperms in the Cretaceous; they hadn't evolved

Googling the keyword *Darwin* and *"abominable mystery"* didn't help me find more results than that. So for those were/are against Darwin's theory of evolution **how often was the 'abominable mystery' used as an argument**?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143106/discussion-on-question-by-qiulang--how-often-was-the-abominable-mystery-used); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The paper cited in the BBC article you linked to is open access: [Richard J.A. Buggs (2021). "The origin of Darwin’s “abominable mystery”". American Journal of Botany 108(1): 22–36](https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/ajb2.1592). Buggs outlines the early use of the origin of flowering plants as an objection to the theory of evolution by Oswald Heer as well as William Carruthers. I suggest you read the paper (or at least pp. 29–32) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: [Heer (1876)](https://archive.org/details/primaevalworldof02heerrich) and [Carruthers (1876)](https://archive.org/details/proceedings29assogoog/page/16/mode/2up) are both available via the Internet Archive.

Comment: Found another interesting article https://ecoevocommunity.nature.com/posts/16792-darwin-s-abominable-mystery .